# 404 (Not Found) SCSS with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

Webpack throws an error

```
GET http://localhost:8080/sass/main.scss net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

but at start server it loaded page with css.
scss imported to js with

```
import '../sass/main.scss';
```

webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
 entry: './src/js/controller.js',

 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
 }),
],
module: {
 rules: [
  {
    test: /\.html$/i,
    use: ['html-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
  },
  ],
 },
}
```

Head part of index.html template: link to css here doesn't influence at all, only import inside js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
 <link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
  family=Nunito+Sans:400,600,700"
  rel="stylesheet"
 />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/src/img/favicon.png" 
  type="image/x-icon" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/saas/main.css" />
 <title></title>
 <script type="module" src="/src/js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have reference to `/sass/main.scss` inside your `index.html`? Can you share the code snippets for `index.html` file?

Comment: I was trying different things (such as edit paths, add to index.html, even resolve-url-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I removed link to script inside index.html

```
<script type="module" src="src/js/controller.js"></script>
```

and error is gone. (entry point and html template are already specified in config)